# Difference between @VisibleForTesting and @Deprecated int unit test

Tags: java, android, unit-testing

Let's say that there just so happens to be an existing long private method (one of which i'm not allowed to refactor into smaller pieces at this stage in the development process) but i really want to write a couple of regression-protection unit test for it, just for now.

i just heard of this `@VisibleForTesting` annotation, but am not too sure of its benefits and gotchas. Previously, i had always been marking things with `@Deprecated` and comments to try and make it VERY CLEAR like:

```
... some code ...
    // ====================================== TESTING USE ONLY BELOW  ======================================
@Deprecated // TESTING ONLY, DO NOT USE!
boolean testGiveAccessToSomethingPrivate() {
    // call some private method and get the results
}
```

it seems that whenever i mark something as `@VisibleForTesting` it seems to expose the method for realz, without any indication to the user of the API that this method was only meant for testing... (whereas if i mark the method with `@Deprecated`, most IDEs will put a strike-through that warns other developers to not accidentally use the test method for their actual code

Comment: `@Deprecated` means will be (most likely) removed in a future version, `@VisibleForTesting` explains why a method is visible. It's not the same thing

Comment: i know, it's not the best convention, but at least there's a strike-through, so that let's say someone else tries to use your API... they would probably really think twice about [potentially accidentally] calling that deprecated method

Comment: First, you should not have method allowing access to something with no usual access in your production code (this is a bad idea). Second, the  "strike-through" is here to show you that the method used is deprecated, not to show you you're using some "for testing purposes" method.

Comment: @RC. totally agree, but hey, suppose i'm not in control of such decisions on that. but still need to have this "unusual access". and yes, strike-through shows deprecation, which has the same desired effect of warning a developer on what's going on

Answer (score 6):

**@Deprecated**

When the method is marked **@Deprecated**, programmers use this method will know maybe this method will be removed, different behavior ... in future version. And if that happen, your code will be broken and you will rework. So, they should use this function very carefully or should replace by other function. (often programmer who made this api will make another similar function without deprecated for you to use).

**@VisibleForTesting**

You have learnt `public` `private` `protected` ... and you use it well. But in real world, everything not as our imagination. For example, your class have a private variable, and you want to test this variable, how can?

```
class SimpleClass() {
   private int a;

   public simpleMethod() {
       if (a < 0) {
          // do something
       } else {
          // do another thing
       }
   }
}
```

One way is changing scope of variable a to package level, because your test file will be same package with file to be tested. But another programmer jumps into and they will ask their self: "Why someone put modifier of a is package level? I think private level is better". (of course, they don't know or don't mind reading your test code because life is so busy). So you will have a way for their to know by using **@VisibleForTesting**. They read this and Google and know: "Ahhhh, I understood. He want this variable is testable".

That's a very short story about those two annotations. The similar is: They **don't change** the way your code run. Not change anything but notify for other people to know something. Very famous annotation every Java Developer knew and similar is **@Override**

The difference is: **@Deprecated** for someone using your code, and **@VisibleForTesting** for someone reading your code. Let make life's programmer easier in both case.

Hope this help :)